# Why does ghci desugar type lists and type families? Can this be selectively disabled?

Tags: haskell, types, ghci

I'm trying to make the types ghci displays for my libraries as intuitive as possible, but I'm running into a lot of difficulties when using more advanced type features.

Let's say I have this code in a file:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

import GHC.TypeLits

data Container (xs::[*]) = Container
```

I load it up in ghci, then I type the following command:

```
ghci> :t undefined :: Container '[String,String,String,String,String]
```

Unfortunately, ghci gives me the rather ugly looking:

```
:: Container
       ((':)
          *
          String
          ((':)
             * String ((':) * String ((':) * String ((':) * String ('[] *))))))
```

ghci has removed the sugar for type level strings.  Is there any way to prevent ghci from doing this and giving me just the pretty version?

---

On a related note, lets say I create a type level `Replicate` function

```
data Nat1 = Zero | Succ Nat1

type family Replicate (n::Nat1) x :: [*]
type instance Replicate Zero x = '[]
type instance Replicate (Succ n) x = x ': (Replicate n x)

type LotsOfStrings = Replicate (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ Zero))))) String
```

Now, when I ask ghci for a type using `LotsOfStrings`:

```
ghci> :t undefined :: Container LotsOfStrings
```

ghci is nice and gives me the pretty result:

```
undefined :: Container LotsOfStrings
```

But if I ask for the `Replicate`d version,

```
ghci> :t undefined :: Container (Replicate (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ (Succ Zero))))) String)
```

ghci substitutes in for the type family when it didn't do that for the type synonym:

```
:: Container
       ((':)
          *
          [Char]
          ((':)
             * [Char] ((':) * [Char] ((':) * [Char] ((':) * [Char] ('[] *))))))
```

Why is ghci doing the substitution for the type family, but not the type synonym?  Is there a way to control when ghci will do the substitution?

Comment: Because type synonyms are designed purely for human consumption - it doesn't make the substitution because it acknowledges that you made the type synonym because you wanted to write/see the type that way. It makes the substitution with the type family because type families are really about calculating/deducing a type, not displaying it.

Comment: The solution to your problem is in your question - make a type synonym if you want to abbreviate.

Comment: @AndrewC Okay, I never realized that was one of the distinctions between type synonyms and families, but that makes sense.  That still leaves the desugaring of type lists though.

Comment: @AndrewC I just thought up another question related to your comment: Why do the types of Strings sometimes get displayed as `[Char]` and sometimes get displayed as `String`?

Comment: I *think* ghci tries to preserve type synonyms it finds in the source. That is, if a function is *declared* to be of type `String->String`, then the type of its result will be displayed as `String`. However if it has to construct a type from pieces, as in e.g. `"abc"` (which is the same as `'a':'b':'c':[]`) there's no synonym to preserve. *This is pure speculation.*

Comment: @n.m.: Note that GHC makes a similar attempt to preserve the names of type variables, when more generic inferred types unify with less generic, explicitly named type variables. I suspect that if the explicit type `String` is unified with type variables `f a` or `[a]`, it will be displayed as `[Char]` afterwards for similar reasons.

Comment: Somebody really should open a bounty on this...

Comment: @pattyd  I had a bounty, and it expired unanswered.

Comment: Whoah, really? I'm sure somebody can answer this...

Answer (score 2):

The workaround that I know of is using :kind. For instance,

> ghci> :kind (Container '[String,String,String,String,String])

Gives:

> ( Container '[String,String,String,String,String]) :: *

While

> ghci> :kind! (Container '[String,String,String,String,String])

Will print something like this:

> Container
>
> ((':)
>
> ```
>   *
>   [Char]
>   ((':)
>      * [Char] ((':) * [Char] ((':) * [Char] ((':) * [Char] ('[] *))))))
> ```

Officially, of course, you're asking ghci a different question with `kind`, but it works. Using `undefined ::` is sort of a workaround anyhow, so I thought this might suffice.

Comment: I was only using `undefined ::` to give an easy example.  The real problem is when you get an error message that has a type of a list of a thousand different types.  It takes up pages to print it out, and is very difficult to parse.

Comment: Yeah, fair enough. Coulda have realized that . I owe you a better answer

Answer (score 2):

This is fixed in upcoming GHC 7.8.

GHC 7.6 prints kinds if a datatype uses PolyKinds. So you see `(':) * String ('[] *)` instead of just `(':) String '[]`.

In GHC 7.8, kinds are no longer shown by default and your datatype is pretty printed as a list, as you would expect. You can use the new flag `-fprint-explicit-kinds` to see explicit kinds as in GHC 7.6. I don't know the reasons for this, presumably explicit kinds were meant to be an aid for understanding PolyKinds.

Answer (score 0):

```
import GHC.TypeLits

data Container (xs::[*]) = Container
```

I load it up in ghci, then I type the following command:

```
:t undefined :: Container '[String,String,String,String,String]
```

Comment: So...? You still get the result back desugared I suppose, i.e. `String ((':) * String ((':) * String ((':) * ...`.